# [reconstuction of surface]how can I calculate the area of a point set?

Tags: cgal

I have met an issue, I would like retrieve the object area from point cloud data, (x y z) format.

The problem is the object is an 'open' surface. ( a twisted paper for example )

I used convex hull 3 to calculate the outlier facets area, then accumulate them as the surface area......

but it is almost 2~3 times than true value.

I think the convex hull built a 'closed' surface and some facets do not exist.  how can I remove those facets?

Please give me some keys.....Thank you very much!!!

Comment: The tile of you post is misleading. Your true question is about reconstructing a surface out of a point set.

Comment: appologieeee,    my title is updated.. and any hints?